# css glued diagonal line to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening.
Already a day I am trying to solve the following problem. I hope very much for your help.

[image]

There is a diagonal line, which should be glued to the text, which is centered in the block.
Website adaptive. Dimensions exhibited in vh/vw and static positioning is not suitable. How can I "stick" one element to another?

Are there any CSS or jQuery ways to implement this task.
My code is below.

```css
span.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
span.line:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1000px;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-96%, 28%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-96%, 28%);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-96%, 28%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-96%, 28%);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-100%, -5%);
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
span.line:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-25%, -10%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-25%, -10%);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-25%, -10%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-25%, -10%);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, -25%);
  left: 21%;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 15vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 24vh 0;
  padding-right: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap h1 span.line:after {
  left: 24%;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap h1 span.line:before {
  left: 20%;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10%;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1;
  max-width: 450px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner h2:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner .button {
  z-index: 150;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: -5%;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner .button a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hello-block .content-block .wrap-header-block .page-title .title-wrap .wrap-inner .button a:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #31e0d2;
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="hello-block">
<div class="container content-block">
  <div class="wrap-header-block">
    <header class="page-title">
      <hgroup>
        <div class="title-wrap">
          <h1><span class="line"></span>title</h1>
          <div class="wrap-inner">
            <h2>very long title</h2>
            <div class="button">
              <a href="#">feedback</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </hgroup>
    </header>
  </div>
</div></section>
```

Comment: Can you define "suitable".

Comment: Also, you have // in your css, which is an error.

Comment: `//` is used to comment in JavaScript, not CSS. In CSS you use `/* comment here */`

Comment: idk why we're talking about comment syntax but `//` works just fine in all major browsers to comment css, it's just not standard.

Comment: @CalvT you are correct unless its LESS or SCSS that was posted

Comment: @zgood I don't really know LESS or SCSS but surely they would compile to `/**/` right?

Comment: @CalvT I believe the comments get removed when compiled. I am not saying you are wrong, I'm just noting that the OP could have posted valid LESS or SCSS

Comment: @zgood thanks, that's interesting. I don't know much about CSS compilers, so any new knowledge is good :)

Comment: If I lay out all of your code, so you can see the entire implementation, it takes a lot of space. Here is laid the basic steps and the necessary code.

Comment: JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mdc1a2wc/)

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. What do you mean, // works fine to comment css? It's an error. It doesn't work fine. If if it did, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/7g1Lf52z/) wouldn't have problems.

Comment: @MrLister - I didn't say it was correct i said it works, which it does when the comment is at the end of the block like it was in the op's original question.

Comment: [bang bang](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/7g1Lf52z/)